# как прочитать значение из ячейки excel?

Tags: python, excel

Надо прочитать из ячейки excel информацию и заполнить переменную.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [`openpyxl`](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/).

***Пример чтения из ячейки `A1`:***

```py
# pip install openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

data = ws['A1'].value
```

Answer (score 1):

Создаем сам файл

```
ws = openpyxl.Workbook()
```

(если файл нужно редактировать, то нужно изменить `.Workbook()` на `.load_workbook("Имя файла.xlsx")`

Создание дефолтного листа

```
wb = ws.active
```

Заполнение ячейки A1

```
wb['A1']="текст, который будет в ячейке"
```

Чтобы вывести значение из ячейки

```
print(wb['A1'].value) #value-значение ячейки
```

В конце обязательно сохраняем файл

```
ws.save("test.xlsx")
```